# Show only users tagged under a certain number (php,sql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

```
table 'users'

id      name          tag
1       kfir          2,4,7,4
2       avi           1,3,2,5
3       sara          6,8,9,3,5
```

How do I show only the users tagged under number "5" ?

my code

```
$result_total = mysql_query("select * from  users") or die(mysql_error());
$total = mysql_num_rows($result_total);
```

Comment: Split the tag field into a separate table and all your problems will disappear. Every time a developer puts comma separated data in a database text field the Dalai Lama eats a kitten.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: This is such basic knowledge that every basic online SQL course will contain examples of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
$result_total = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('5',`tag`)");
$total = mysql_num_rows($result_total);
```

Also try not to use MySQL and use MySQLi instead.

Comment: -1, tacky workaround for the real problem, this operator should only be [used with real sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, I've used it on even `text` field types and it's working just fine. What's wrong with it then?

Comment: @SAVAFA "but it works" is the worst argument possible for implementing a solution. `FIND_IN_SET` internally does just a string match if not used on a set - it's slow, unmaintainable and unscalable. The proper solution is a separate `UserInTag` table with a proper join, it'll be 100 times faster now and 10000 times faster once the tables start growing.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, I didn't use the "but it works" argument in here! I just said it is working with `text` field type too and does not "require" specific field type. Also, are you numbers and speed factors (being 100 and 10000 times faster) based on performance tests? Because in my case even with more than 10k sets in a single database field, the row retrieval is pretty much fast and no lag is noticeable!

Comment: With sets it *should* be instant, that is what `FIND_IN_SET` is for. For doing a messy string search that can *never* properly use an index, the 10000 might be a low estimate once the table gets to thousands of rows and he has users participating in 1000 tags.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, one question regarding your solution. Imagine that there is 10K+ rows of properties in a table that are related to a row in other table, instead of having on field in that single row in the second table. In case you want to edit some of them, what is the best way to do so? Do you delete all the rows and insert new ones? In my way of using the comma separated text field, I just need to update the row. How would be it be done in your proposed way? I bet there should be a better way than deleting and inserting rows.

Comment: @SAVAFA yes, deleting and inserting is the normal way of doing that. It's what relational databases are optimized to do, and what they do best - joining and adding/deleting lots of rows, not doing complex string matching on text fields.

Answer (score 1):

Also, for a non my-sql specific solution, you could use:

```
select * from users where ','+tag+',' like '%,5,%'
```

Comment: what if `5` is at the very beginning, like `'5,6,8'` (or even at the end)?

Comment: It would still work because we add a comma before the tag field (','+tag+',') above. This makes sure there is always a comma before and after the tag.